# C++ Covariance and references

Tags: c++, reference, covariance, return-type

Lets say I have an abstract base class with a pure virtual that returns an expensive object.  As it's an expensive object, I should return a reference to it.

But life's not that simple, let's say I have two classes derived from it: one has the function called often, so it is more efficient to store a copy in the instance and return a reference.  The other is called rarely, so it is better to create the object on demand to save RAM.

I thought I could just use covariance because the Liskov substitution principle would be happy, but of course `Obj` is not a subtype of `Obj&`, so compile errors result.

```
class abc
{
public:
    virtual BigObj& obj() = 0;
};

class derived : public abc
{
public:
    ...
    virtual BigObj obj() { return obj_; }

private:
    BigObj obj_;
};
```

Results in:

```
conflicting return type specified for ‘virtual BigObj derived::obj()’
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this than simply picking the least worst?

Comment: Simple answer is *you don't want to do this*. You may *think* that you want this, but you don't really want to do this. The change in semantics of returning a value or a reference are too big to be *hidden* from user code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to create a smart pointer class to manage `BigObj*`s:

```
class BigObjPtr {
public:
    BigObjPtr(bool del, BigObj* ptr) : del(del), ptr(ptr) { }

    BigObj* operator->() {
        return ptr;
    }

    virtual ~BigObjPtr() {
        if (del) delete ptr;
    }

private:
    BigObj* ptr;
    bool del;
};
```

Then change your classes to return one of these, and set the `del` bool to whether you want the `BigObjPtr` to destroy its pointer when it goes out of scope:

```
class abc
{
public:
    virtual BigObjPtr obj() = 0;
};

class derived : public abc
{
public:
    ...
    BigObjPtr obj() { return BigObjPtr(false, &obj_); }

private:
    BigObj obj_;
};

class otherderived : public abc
{
public:
    ...
    BigObjPtr obj() { return BigObjPtr(true, new BigObj); }
};
```

You'd of course need to manage copying of `BigObjPtr`s, etc. but I leave that to you.

Comment: You and Benjamin Lindley are spot on, great answer.

Comment: The pattern `if (del) delete del;` marks redundancy: Default `delete` is well-defined on null pointers. Just `delete del;` works.

Comment: @Konrad it's not `if (del) delete del;` it's `if (del) delete ptr;` so I'm not checking whether `ptr` is `NULL`. So it's not doing what you think it is :)

Comment: @Set Dude, I’m too sleepy. Sorry to bother you. Have an upvote.

Comment: Note that this solution (well, not actually the solution, but the problem itself) violates the Liskov substitution principle. If a function calls on this virtual function, and applies some mutating operation on the returned object, in one case (original return by reference) the change will be visible by all other callers to the function (warning: not safe for multithreading eiher!), while if the final overrider is of a different type the changes applied to the object will be discarded at the end of the scope, i.e. the behavior of the rest of the program depends on the real type.

Answer (score 3):

You should rethink your assumptions, the interface of the functions should be defined in terms of what the semantics are. So the main question is *what are the semantics of the function?*

If your function *creates* an object, regardless of how big or small it is to copy you should return by value regardless of how often the code is called. If on the other hand, what you are doing is providing access to an already existing object, then you should return a reference to the object, in *both* cases.

Note that:

```
expensive function() {
   expensive result;
   return result;
}
expensive x = function();
```

Can be optimized by the compiler into a single `expensive` object (it can avoid copying from `result` to the returned object and elide the copy from the returned object into `x`).

On the Liskov substitution principle, you are not following here, one type is returning an object, and the other is returning a *reference to an object*, which are completely different things in many aspects, so even if you can apply *similar* operations to the two returned types, the fact is that there are other operations that are not the same, and there are different responsibilities that are passed to the caller.

For example, if you modify the returned object in the reference case, you are changing the value of *all* returned objects from the function in the future, while in the value case the object is *owned* by the caller and it does not matter what the caller does to its copy, the next call to the function will return a newly created object without those changes.

So again, *think* on what the semantics of your function are and use that to define what to return in all deriving classes. If you are not sure how expensive the piece of code is, you can come back with a simplified use case and we can discuss how to improve the performance of the application. For that you will need to be explicit in what user code does with the objects it gets, and what it expects from the function.

Comment: Interesting point!  I should have given the Wikipedia LSP page more than cursory glance...

Answer (score 2):

Return a `shared_ptr<BigObj>` instead.  One class can keep it's own copy around, the other can create it on demand.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. As you noted, you can pick the least worst. That is, pick `BigObj` or `BigObj&` for both derived classes.
2. You could add new methods to the derived classes that have the appropriate return types. eg, `BigObj& obj_by_ref()` and `BigObj obj_by_val()`.

The reason you can't have it both ways is because you might have a pointer to `abc` directly. It specifies `BigObj&`, so no matter which class provides the implementation, it had better return an `BigObj&`, because that's what the call site expects. If a misbehaving subclass returned an `BigObj` directly, it would cause mayhem when the compiler tried to use it as a reference!

Answer (score 0):

Return by reference is dangerous in most cases as it can lead to hard to track memory issues, for example when the parent object goes out of scope or deleted. I would redesign the BigObj to be a simple delegate (or container) class that actually holds the pointer to expensive object.

Comment: Unless you track ownership (`shared_ptr`), a pointer won’t give you any more safety than a reference: when the parent object goes out of scope, the destructor is called and (hopefully) frees the pointers it owns.